# expect_to_receive not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use `expect_to_receive` rspec expectation but without any luck. My controller specs file looks like that:

```
it 'resolves an end behaviour' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Job).to receive(:resolve_end_behaviour)

  post :callback, @params
end
```

And my controller method:

```
def callback
  @video = JobVideo.find(params['body']['id'].to_i)
  if !@video.is_ready
    @video.job.resolve_end_behaviour
    @video.update_attribute(:is_ready, true)
  end

  render json: { success: true }
end
```

And running `rspec` gives me:

```
Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: resolve_end_behaviour
```

I'm sure that this method is called cause `is_ready` column is beeing updated. Can anyone give me any clues on why is that happening and what can i do about it? Thanks in advance.

Env:

- rails 4
- rspec 3

Comment: Could you print out what's `@video.job`? Also add a print from _inside_ the `resolve_end_behaviour` to see that it is actually called

Answer (score 1):

Your test is expecting resolve_end_behaviour to be called with two arguments, you are calling it with no arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that. After removing the `with` part, error is still there

Comment: Are you certain that @video.job.is_a? Job

That would certainly send your test astray if it's not the right object type